# Clear CSS from all child Element

Tags: html, css

I have to add content from admin side with ckditor and I want to show same content display on front side.

My front CSS is going to change but how can i prevent and remove all css for only one div and that div withing ol, ul and many more stuff.

Comment: Can you provide some code? Its easier to get good answers if you give something to work on.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove CSS from an element using CSS.
Instead you have to overwrite it using more specific CSS.

E.g.

```
.class { background: red; }
```

is overwritten by

```
.parent .class { background: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery removeClass() function

```
$('#mydiv').removeClass('myClass1 myClass2')
```

where myClass1 and myClass2 are classed generated by ckditor

Comment: Doesn't this assume the class is attached to the element?